# BuddyPress Custom Nav and Page Template

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using buddypress for a social media site.

I have create an xprofile field called "About", and also added a new tab in the buddypress pages using the following code.

```
function custom_setup_nav() {
  global $bp;

  bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 
        'name' => __( 'About', 'buddypress' ), 
        'slug' => 'about', 
        'position' => 30, 
        'screen_function' => 'about_page'
  ) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'custom_setup_nav' );
```

Now I have created an about page and named it about.php and uploaded it to /plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/members/single

And then added the following screen function

```
function about_page() {
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/about' ) );
}
```

Now when I go to about page, I always get the members page displayed there, the page where the list of members are displayed and not the custom about.php page that I have uploaded, although the url remains the same, members/username/about/

Is there something I am missing out on ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the path you have used in bp_core_load_template

Comment: Its not about the path, no matter what I enter there, it keeps on going to the members page. I have asked the same question in buddypress forum http://buddypress.org/support/topic/buddypress-custom-nav-and-page-template-2/

Comment: I've wrote an answer as it was too long for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to have a **subnav** item. Try changing your `custom_setup_nav` function to:

```
global $bp;
bp_core_new_nav_item( 
  array( 'name' => __( 'About', 'buddypress' ), 
    'slug'  => 'about',  
    'position' => 30,
    'show_for_displayed_user' => true,
    'default_subnav_slug' => 'about',
    'item_css_id' => 'about'
  ) 
);

bp_core_new_subnav_item( 
  array( 'name' => __( 'About', 'buddypress' ), 
    'slug' => 'about', 
    'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . 'about', 
    'screen_function' => 'about_page',
    'parent_slug' => 'about', 
    'position' => 10, 
    'item_css_id' => 'about' 
  )
);
```

Also, try creating a folder in your theme directory called `/buddypress/` then use the path:

```
/buddypress/members/single/about
```

That will ensure your customisations aren't lost each time you upgrade BP. See here for more info on the template hierarchy: http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/

Comment: sub nav item ? Its a tab on the main menu of buddypress, not sure if thats the sub nav, here is the link to the page http://tinyurl.com/m8y7zkm

Comment: **all** of the member main-nav items have a subnav item which is why I believe you _need_ to have a subnav item. Take a look at the way BP Followers code does it (it's written by a core developer) and you'll see how the BP nav system works https://github.com/r-a-y/buddypress-followers

Comment: /buddypress/members/single/about What does this line mean, i have to create a folder /about/ and upload about.php there ?

Comment: "i have to create a folder /about/ and upload about.php there" - No. Actually `/about` is a reference to your `about.php` file without the `.php` extension. So you would put your `about.php` file in the `/single/` folder

Comment: Adapted, it worked for me. However, I had to change
`'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . 'about',`
to
`'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . 'about/',`